# When I return a FileContentResult from Controller.File, the download stalls at 128kb

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

My controller is returning `File(res.File, "application/octet-stream", res.Filename);` where res.File is an array of bytes.

I am running this controller using Kestrel, and this works fine for files are are under 128kb in size.  Any larger, however, and the download of the file from the api simply stalls out at 128kb.

I'm clearly missing something.  I can't find any reference to a limit for this kind of stuff.

I tried decorating the controller method with `[DisableRequestSizeLimit]`, but oddly enough this made it start choking at 64kb.

I'm running dotnet 5.

**Controller method**

```cs
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/v1/reports/get-report")]
        public FileResult DownloadReport(
            string system,
            string environment,
            string company,
            string quoteNumber,
            string template,
            string user)
        {
            var req = new GetQuoteReportRequest()
            {
                System = system,
                Environment = environment,
                Company = company,
                QuoteNumber = quoteNumber,
                Template = template,
                User = user
            };
            return GenerateReportFile(req);
        }

        private FileResult GenerateReportFile(GetQuoteReportRequest req)
        {
            var res = _quoteReportService.GetQuoteReport(req);
            return File(res.File, "application/octet-stream", res.Filename);
        }
```

**Service method**

```cs
        public GetQuoteReportResponse GetQuoteReport(GetQuoteReportRequest req)
        {
            var message = $"Generate {req.Template} report for quote {req.QuoteNumber}";
            _logger.LogInformation($"START: {message}");
            var res = new GetQuoteReportResponse();
            var time = _timeService.Now;
            var excelFilePath = GetExcelFilePath(time, req.QuoteNumber);
            var quote = _dataLoader.GetQuote(req, IncludeInternalQuoteDetailLines);

            using var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
            var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add(req.QuoteNumber);
            Builder.BuildReport(worksheet,
                quote,
                req);

            workbook.SaveAs(excelFilePath);

            if (IsPdf)
            {
                var pdfFilePath = CreatePdf(excelFilePath);
                res.Filename = Path.GetFileName(pdfFilePath);
                res.File = File.ReadAllBytes(pdfFilePath);
            }
            else
            {
                res.File = File.ReadAllBytes(excelFilePath);
                res.Filename = Path.GetFileName(excelFilePath);
            }

            _utilities.SendDbEntry(time,
                Path.GetFileName(res.Filename),
                quote.QuoteLines.Count,
                req);
            
            _logger.LogInformation($"END: {message}");

            return res;
        }
```

Comment: full code please

Comment: @CaiusJard I've included the controller method in the edited question.  Thanks!

Comment: How does `_quoteReportService.GetQuoteReport` look like?

Comment: @GSerg I've included the service method in the edited question.  Thanks!

Comment: And if you log `res.File.Length`, what do you get?

Comment: @AdamSkinner This might be a case of not properly disposing  `workbook`. Consider refactoring your `using` statement with brackets in the proper place. You are reading the file before the using goes out of scope so chances are the data has not been flushed by the time you try to read it

Comment: @Nkosi The workbook isn't the source of the output; it saves to the filesystem (because we've got an integration yoinking this stuff into Sharepoint), and it's that (valid) file that is the source of the bytes in the response.

Comment: I am saying that based on your shown code, it could be that you are trying to read the file before all the data has been properly saved to it. Humor  me and properly dispose of the wookbook as you troubleshoot the problem since this might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Nkosi I gave disposing it a shot, but no luck.